# Selected Value for combobox not working for DirectCast or CType

Tags: vb.net, combobox, controls

I am trying to clear out the selection of a combobox on my form, but when setting the `.SelectedValue` property to -1, I instead get whatever the first value is.

To explain `headerControls` and `controlsList`, I create all of my controls at runtime from a config file, loaded into `controlsList` and when I add the control to the screen I also add it to `headerControls`

```
Public headerControls As New Dictionary(Of String, Control)

Try
    For each dynamicControl As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, CustomControl) In controlsList 
        Select dynamicControl.Value.ControlType.ToLower()
            Case "textbox"
                DirectCast(headerControls.Item(dynamicControl.Value.ControlName), TextBox).Text = ""
            Case "combobox"
                DirectCast(headerControls.Item(dynamicControl.Value.ControlName), ComboBox).SelectedValue = -1
        End Select
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
        'Error Handling
End Try
```

The code that creates the controls:

```
Try
    For each dynamicControl As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, CustomControl) In controlsList 

        Select Case dynamicControl.Value.ControlType.ToLower()
            Case "textbox"
                Dim textBoxControl As New TextBox

                With textBoxControl
                    'Set Textbox properties here
                End With

                headerControls.Add(dynamicControl.Value.ControlName, textBoxControl)
                Controls.Add(textBoxControl)

            Case "combobox"
                Dim comboBoxControl As New ComboBox

                With comboBoxControl
                    'Set ComboBox properties here
                End With

                LoadCombo(comboBoxControl)

                headerControls.Add(dynamicControl.Value.ControlName, comboBoxControl)
                Controls.Add(comboBoxControl)

        End Select
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    'Error Handling
End Try
```

Clearing the text boxes works, but ComboBox is not showing the same behavior as if I placed one on the screen and used `.SelectedValue = -1`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should check the difference between `SelectedValue` and `SelectedIndex`. Setting `SelectedValue` to a value can't possibly select no item. If you want no item selected then you set `SelectedIndex` to -1, `SelectedItem` to `Nothing` or, depending on your binding, `SelectedValue` to `Nothing`.

Comment: I tried the `SelectedItem` and was receiving the same result, but if I did it twice, it would clear the selection... not exactly sure why though